# Interstitial ads not showing

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm trying to add ads on my APP, the problem is that I've followed the [Getting Started in AdMob for Android](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start), and the ads aren't being shown up.

I've added on my `manifest.xml` the following:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

And I've added ***two permissions*** as follows:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Then, I've added an `Activity` also:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

I want the [`INTERSTITIAL AD`](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial); As far as I know, there are the ads that fill the screen... So, I tried this:

On my `MainActivity.java` I've added the following:

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();

        }
});
```

On my `activity_main.xml` I've added the following:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/Home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

However, the ad is being never shown... When I see the `LogCat` I can't see any error... So, what I'm missing?

*I don't want the banner; I want the full-screen ads. Shen I created the AD-Mob publisher-ID, I put 7 seconds; however, it isn't appeared...*

### EDIT

I've get something... I've read some tutorials and I think I've found the way to do it... here's my code now :

MainActivity.java

```
end_ad=new InterstitialAd(this);
end_ad.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
end_ad.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

And on my Activity on an `onClickListener()` I've added this code :

```
if(end_ad.isLoaded()){
    end_ad.show();
    Log.d(TAG,"SHOWING");
}
else{
    Log.d(TAG, "NOT SHOWING");
}
```

But only it's shown once... Any idea why?

Comment: Banner ad unit id for a interstitial unit? See: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial?hl=en

Comment: That's the tutorial I've followed too... I don't get what you want to say yo me

Comment: R.string.banner_ad_unit_id has what string value? And if its a banner why aren't you using the interstitial value as defined in the doc.

Comment: For what size is your Ad Unit ID?

Comment: I tried to put `ads:adSize="INTERSTITIAL"` but doesn't work

Comment: Edited my question..

Comment: Can you try with passing your device id in ad request builder

Comment: without using strings? AD is working but only once... I don't know if it's the problem

Comment: I am referring to private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
              .addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_HASH")
              .build();

    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}

Comment: So everytime I want to show up this ADS I call this function?

Comment: I run it on a real device that's why I don't add a TestDevice... @androgeek

Comment: After each display you need to again call loadAd to fetch an Interstitial, once available you should call show() to display same. During dev/testing it is better to pas your hashed device id (for real devices) in loadAd(), to know hashed id you should check logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it doing ...

Creating a `InterstitialAd`

```
private InterstitialAd end_ad;
```

Inside on `onCreate()` initializing it as follows :

```
//ADS
    end_ad=new InterstitialAd(this);
    end_ad.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id);
    end_ad.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Then I've created a method called `displayInterstitial` that looks like :

```
 public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial(end_ad) else show nothing.
    if (end_ad.isLoaded()) {
        end_ad.show();
    }
}
```

Then on every `onClickListener()` I call this method to show ads, it will only show once unless you make a `finish()` on current `Activity` or remove from recents.

Comment: I had a question on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389729/ads-are-loading-but-not-showing/36389781?noredirect=1#comment60396446_36389781

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I hadn't completed my payment info.